# Derive pdf of slash distribution, standard normal divided by standard uniform

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, transformation, uniform-distribution

Let $U$ be a standard uniform distribution, and $Z$ be a standard normal distribution. $Z$ and $U$ are independent. Let $X=Z/U$, and find the pdf of $X$.

I searched around the internet and all answers used some advanced results in ratio distribution, but I don't think this is what I'm expected to do. I want to know if I can only use ways like CDF or transformation methods to find the pdf of $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So maybe we can use the cdf. Note that $f_U(u) = \mathbb{I}_{[0,1]}$, so:
$$
\begin{split}
F_X(x)
 &= \mathbb{P}[X \le x] \\
 &= \int_0^1 \mathbb{P}[Z/U \le x|U = u] \cdot f_U(u)\ du \\
 &= \int_0^1 \mathbb{P}[Z \le xu] \cdot 1\ du \\
 &= \int_0^1 \Phi(xu) du.
\end{split}
$$
Now differentiate to get the pdf.

Comment: How to evaluate this integral and thus find its derivative? I'm not that familiar with it

Comment: @Nonenicht the integral is a function of $x$, just like the LHS. To find the pdf, you want to say that $$f_X(x) = \frac{d}{dx} F_X(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^1 \Phi(xu)du$$ and the apply the [Leibniz Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign)